# GResource, GtkBuilder and gettext translations

Tags: resources, gtk, gettext, gtkbuilder

I'm using Meson (with glib gettext preset) to bundle GtkBuilder files in a GResource file, but I can't figure how to get gettext to recognize the translatable strings.

I've marked the strings with the `translatable` attribute, put the `domain` attribute on the `<interface>` element and listed the file in my GResource xml and POTFILE, but the strings don't appear in the generated pot.

I've seen a number of projects in C such as [this one](https://github.com/csoriano1618/minapp) which don't use the `domain` attribute on the interface, but either way I get no results.

How can I get my translatable GtkBuilder files to be recognized?

Comment: You are trying to achieve what, exactly?

Comment: Try giving a look at how GNOME Recipes does it: https://github.com/matthiasclasen/gr . They use meson (and not autotools like the example you gave), they compile resources (see `src/meson.build`) and the strings are marked as translatable in the resource file.

Comment: @theGtknerd I'm trying to get gettext to recognize translatable string in a file compiled into a gresource bundle

Comment: @liberforce I've tried this the same way, but with the exception that I'm not building a C program so I'm compiling a gresource file instead of into a binary. I feel like this might be what is causing the problem and maybe I should just avoid GResource.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with GResource to answer that question, but I suggest you ask on the [gtk-app-devel mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gtk-app-devel-list).

Comment: supposing your meson files are correct. Did you try `ninja <project-name>-pot` and `ninja <project-name>-update-po` (eg. `ninja myapp-pot`, `ninja myapp-update-po`)?

Comment: Yep, I ran all the usual meson gettext updates, although honestly I'm not sure how gettext would find it in the GResource, before or after the compilation. The file path in my POTFILE is the local source, but after the path will obviously be a `resource:///` path. I have a feeling this might need to be supported by gettext itself.

Comment: Well, I use Glade/Builder UI files as resources and get the translatable strings at the generated pot/po files. So i guess there must be something wrong with the meson files and/or project structure. Not sure what the problem may be... !?

Comment: Do build them into a binary, or do you build "bundles" ie `org.foo.gresource`?

Comment: @andy.holmes They are setup as resources, so they get built into the binary. Images, icons etc are bundled but the ui files are retrieved with the *_get_from_resource methods/functions.